# How to declare an array with a fixed number of fixed-sized strings in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling

Basically what I need is an array of strings, where the array has 4 elements and each string is exactly 16 bytes.

Currently I'm using this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string1; // 16 Byte String

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string2; // 16 Byte String

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string3; // 16 Byte String

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string4; // 16 Byte String
}
```

But what I want is like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public struct SomeStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string[4] strings; // 4 times 16 Byte String

}
```

I know you can also use MarshalAs to fix the size of an array:

```
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    private byte[] bytes;            // 4 Byte
```

How can I achieve what I need?

It is important that the sizes don't change in any way since I'm receiving a byte[] that contains my struct data, so changing the sizes or order messes up everything.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that purely through marshalling. Get your byte array and split it into 4 strings procedurally.

Comment: @MatthewWatson when using Marshal.SizeOf() onto the structure, it returns 64 bytes size though. Also the data I'm receiving would be messed up if the string size was 32-byte, which isn't the case. I didn't specify UTF8 anywhere. I don't know why but it works :D

Comment: Ah - the Microsoft documentation I looked at was misleading. For strings, it IS characters. I've removed my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out a couple of things, I found a solution (or at least an acceptable workaround) for my problem. I changed the struct to class and implemented some extra methods:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public class SomeClass
{
    public string[] strings()
    {
        string[] strs = new string[4];
        strs[0] = string1;
        strs[1] = string2;
        strs[2] = string3;
        strs[3] = string4;
    }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string1; // 16 Byte String

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string2; // 16 Byte String

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string3; // 16 Byte String

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string string4; // 16 Byte String
}
```

For other data types it is much easier, for example I needed my booleans to be 1 byte instead of the default 4 byte:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public class SomeClass
{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool[] bs; // 8 times 1 Byte boolean

}
```

SizeConst defines the number of array elements, whereas ArraySubType can be used to define the array data type.